# Adding Jquery select dropdown box to refine search using raphael USA map

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using a jquery map to populate my url by state clicked.  For example, when someone clicks WA state from the map the url is updated to http://example.com/classes.php?WA, I am using

```
if(isset($_SERVER[ 'QUERY_STRING' ])) {
$state = escape($_SERVER[ 'QUERY_STRING' ]);
```

to capture the url query being passed so I can search in MYSQL and pull up all results in WA state. It's working perfectly!  I also wish to add a select dropdown to the mix so class names can be searched by state and by class id.  The problem is I am having difficulty populating the url properly with the added values from the select in order to refine my search.  Does anyone have any idea how to do this?  I am using raphael.js for the map.  The select drop down would be providing the value class_id with all the values I have for my classes.

[USA JQuery Map](https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/)

I have

```
$(".classpicker").change(function () {

var selectedtext = $(".classpicker option:selected").html();
// alert("select value of contact type is" + selectedtext);
<?php $url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>
window.location = "<?php echo $url . '?'; ?>" + this.value;
```

});

Comment: but every time I click the select dropdown box it adds another ?value to the url which is bad.  I am looking for a way to preserve the http://example.com/classes.php?WA and just add the & class_id to the url, without it adding a new one every time. I am ending up with url's like http://example.com/classes.php?WA?7?18?14  I want it to preserve the state abbreviation and add a &  + the class_id every time a class is selected from the dropdown box.

Comment: ideal url for parsing:  http://example.com/classes.php?WA&10 if class_id 10 is selected from the dropdown box.
or http://example.com/classes.php?11 if no state was chosen and class_id 11 was chosen from the dropdown box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// If a value is passed to the url from either map or dropdown JQuery or search field
if(isset($_GET['p_id'])) {

$value = escape($_GET[ 'p_id' ]);

    if(ctype_alpha($value)) { // If it's letters

        $state = escape($_GET[ 'p_id' ]);

    } else { // otherwise it's an integar

        $class = escape($_GET[ 'p_id' ]);

    }
    }
```